# XPath query condition to express: "set does not contain any/all" or "set contains any/all"

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML (from W3Schools):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Is there a way to return the set of books that satisfy:

1. Any of (A, B, ...) exist as authors?
2. All of (A, B, ...) exist as authors?
3. Any of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors?
4. All of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors together?

where (A, B, ...) is a set of author names.

Comment: what do you mean by (A,B,... )? I don't understand yet what you want. Have you trief sth? What? Resultat?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are all the wanted expressions**. I assume that the set of names is provided not as just set of strings (there is no such notion in XPath 1.0), but as a node-set, the string value of each node of which is one of the names that we must have.

I am also using XSLT 1.0 so that I can show the result of the evaluation of each of the four XPath expressions.

As set of author names I chose the author names of the book titled "XQuery Kick Start".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAuthors" select="/*/*[3]/author"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  1. Any of (A, B, ...) exist as authors: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select="boolean($vAuthors[. = /*/*/author])"/>

  2. All of (A, B, ...) exist as authors: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select="not($vAuthors[not(. = /*/*/author)])"/>

  3. Any of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select="not($vAuthors[. = /*/*/author])"/>

  4. All of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors together: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
    "not(/*/*[count(author[. = $vAuthors]) = count($vAuthors)])"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

**the XPath expressions are evaluated and their results are copied to the output:**

```
  1. Any of (A, B, ...) exist as authors: true

  2. All of (A, B, ...) exist as authors: true

  3. Any of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors: false

  4. All of (A, B, ...) should not exist as authors together: false
```